# How to double check if checkbox is selected before deleting a row

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have checkbox in gridview for delete a selectin item, and on asp.net I have to to get the 3 index value of check box which separated by (,) and each row separated by (|), if user select the check box once and click on the delete key I does delete the selected row which fine, but if user check and uncheck a same row, must not to delete a row, but it does still delete it if check and uncheck before click on the delete key.
Can u help me for my code please?

```
Asp. Net code:


<asp:Panel ID="panLegalRecords" runat="server" ScrollBars="Vertical" ClientIDMode="static" Width="890">
                            <asp:GridView ID="gvLegalRecords" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ClientCode,DebtorNumber,DebtorName,DebtorSSN" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowCommand="gvLegalRecords_RowCommand" OnSorting="gvLegalRecords_Sorting" OnSelectedIndexChanging="gvLegalRecords_SelectedIndexChanging" OnRowDeleting="gvLegalRecords_RowDeleting" OnRowDataBound="gvLegalRecords_RowDataBound" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" AllowSorting="True" Width="98%">
                                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#73B1E8" ForeColor="#ffffff" Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="8" />
                                <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#000000" />
                                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#ffffff" ForeColor="#000000" />
                                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#336699" ForeColor="#ffffff" />
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DELETE">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkDeleteKey" runat="server" Checked="false"  OnClick="document.getElementById('hfLegalRecords').value =  document.getElementById('hfLegalRecords').value + this.checked + ',' + this.parentNode.parentNode.cells[2].innerHTML + ',' + this.parentNode.parentNode.cells[3].innerHTML + '|';" />
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Image" DeleteImageUrl="~/Images/48/delete-row.png" SelectImageUrl="~/Images/48/select-row.png" ShowDeleteButton="true" ShowSelectButton="true">
                                        <ItemStyle Font-Size="8pt" Width="10%" />
                                    </asp:CommandField>

                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ClientCode" HeaderText="Client Code">
                                        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                        <ItemStyle Font-Size="8pt" HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="10%" />
                                    </asp:BoundField>
                                    <asp:BoundField DataField="DebtorNumber" HeaderText="Debtor Number">
                                        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                        <ItemStyle Font-Size="8pt" HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="10%" />
                                    </asp:BoundField>
</columns>

    protected void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] Checked = hfLegalRecords.Value.Split('|');
        for (int i = 0; i < Checked.Length - 1; ++i)
        {
            Boolean checkSelect = false;

            string[] value = Checked[i].Split(',');

            string checkbox = value[0];
            string ClientCode = value[1];
            string DebtorNumber = value[2];
            for (int j = 0; j < Checked.Length - 1; ++j)
            {
                string[] valueS = Checked[j].Split(',');
                string checkboxS = valueS[0];
                string ClientCodeS = valueS[1];
                string DebtorNumberS = valueS[2];
                if (ClientCode == ClientCodeS && DebtorNumber == DebtorNumberS)
                    checkSelect = true;
            }
            if (checkSelect == true)
                LegalEvents.RemoveSelectCheckBox(ClientCode, DebtorNumber);
        }
        LoadLegalRecords();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I would recommend you to split the data sent by the hidden field into more than one hidden field, instead of using one hidden field and using string.Split().
Also would recommend you to extract the JavaScript event to populate the hidden field, to a function. 
It will make the code way easier to maintain and way less error-prone.

Second, I have hard times understanding what your code is supposed to do because of the note mentioned above.
But I assume your problem comes from iterating over the same values over and over.
Both of your loops iterate for (Checked.Length -1) times, and you basically check if arr[i] == arr[i] which will always be true.
And therefore always will execute `LegalEvents.RemoveSelectCheckBox(ClientCode, DebtorNumber);`